# Why does passing `const char[N]` and `const char*` to view::c_str() yield different binaries, while string_view produces the same?

Tags: c++, optimization, range-v3, string-view

With `std::string_view`, `range::for_each` yields *exact* assembly with both `const char[N]` and `const char *` passing to `std::string_view` ctor

In other words, this code

```
auto str = "the quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\nthe quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\n";
ranges::for_each(std::string_view{str}, std::putchar);
```

and

```
auto& str = "the quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\nthe quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\n";
ranges::for_each(std::string_view{str}, std::putchar);
```

both yield below assembly :

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    $-90, %rbx
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movsbl  .L.str+90(%rbx), %edi
        movq    stdout(%rip), %rsi
        callq   _IO_putc
        addq    $1, %rbx
        jne     .LBB0_1
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rbx
        retq
.L.str:
        .asciz  "the quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\nthe quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\n"
```

Moreover, if we pass a c string as `const char[N]` to `ranges::view::c_str()`,

```
auto& str = "the quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\nthe quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\n";
ranges::for_each(ranges::view::c_str(str), std::putchar);
```

this yields the exact assembly above like one `std::string_view` produces.

---

On the other hand, If we pass a c string as `const char*` to `ranges::view::c_str()`

```
auto str = "the quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\nthe quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\n";
ranges::for_each(ranges::view::c_str(str), std::putchar);
```

This time it yields a different assembly as below:

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rbx
        movb    $116, %al
        movq    $-90, %rbx
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movsbl  %al, %edi
        movq    stdout(%rip), %rsi
        callq   _IO_putc
        movzbl  .L.str+91(%rbx), %eax
        incq    %rbx
        jne     .LBB0_1
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rbx
        retq
.L.str:
        .asciz  "the quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\nthe quick brown fox is jumping on a lazy dog\n"
```

---

Which assembly wins?

Why does `std::string_view` decide to yield the same binary?

Could `view::c_str()` yield only one faster assembly with both `const char*` and `const char [N]`?

[godbolt.org/g/wcQyY1](https://godbolt.org/g/wcQyY1)

Comment: I suggest you to squeeze in `c++` tag. It's a lot more popular than version-specific c++ tags.

Answer (score 5):

Both `std::string_view` versions call the same constructor, which takes a `const char*` and then uses `std::char_traits::length` (which is basically `strlen`) to find the length. The compiler optimizes away the `strlen` because the string literal is visible to the compiler so its length is known, but both forms use the exact same constructor, and both optimize away the `strlen`, and so both generate the same code.

The `view::c_str` version uses different overloads depending whether it's given a pointer or an array, see https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/1f4a96e9240786801e95a6c70afebf27f04cffeb/include/range/v3/view/c_str.hpp#L68

When given a pointer it has to find the length similarly to using `strlen`, but when given an array of size `N` it uses `N-1` for the length. Even when the compiler optimizes away the `strlen`-like code to a fixed compile-time value, it's still compiling something different, so it's not entirely surprising that the generated code is not identical.

Comment: That's very interesting. It seems compilers are very good at optimizing out `strlen`. I just found out that `ranges::span<const char>(str,strlen(str))` also yield exactly the first version. [godbolt.org/g/HSebUR](https://godbolt.org/g/HSebUR)